# Android Retrofit 2.0 Get issue

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, androidhttpclient

I am using retrofit 2.0 and i have post request with token and userId and in response i get an jsonobject containing arraylist

The structure of response is as below

```
{
 "communities": [
   {
     "commId": 1,
     "name": "Enginnering"
   },
   {
     "commId": 2,
     "name": "Student"
   },
    {
     "commId": 3,
     "name": "Banking"
   },
   {
     "commId": 4,
     "name": "Teacher"
   },
   {
     "commId": 5,
     "name": "Government"
   },
   {
     "commId": 6,
     "name": "Political"
   }
 ]
}
```

The model class structure is as below

```
    CommunityModel implements Serializable{

    public static final String KEY_COMMUNITY_ID = "commId";
    public static final String KEY_COMMUNITY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_CREATED_AT="c_at";
    public static final String KEY_UPDATED_AT="u_at";
    public static final String KEY_AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    public static final String KEY_COMMUNITIES="communities";

    @SerializedName(KEY_COMMUNITY_ID)
    int communityid;

    @SerializedName(KEY_COMMUNITY_NAME)
    String communityName;

    @SerializedName(KEY_CREATED_AT)
    String createdAt;

    @SerializedName(KEY_UPDATED_AT)
    String updatedAt;


    public CommunityModel(int communityid, String communityName, String createdAt, String updatedAt)
    {
        this.communityid=communityid;
        this.communityName=communityName;
        this.createdAt=createdAt;
        this.updatedAt=updatedAt;
    }

    public int getCommunityid() {
        return communityid;
    }

    public void setCommunityid(int communityid) {
        this.communityid = communityid;
    }

    public String getCommunityName() {
        return communityName;
    }

    public void setCommunityName(String communityName) {
        this.communityName = communityName;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

My retrofit interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/v1/communities/")
    Call<ArrayList<CommunityModel>> getCommunities(
            @Query(CommunityModel.KEY_AUTHORIZATION) String servertoken,
            @Field(UserAccount.KEY_USER_ID) int type,
            @Field(CommunityModel.KEY_COMMUNITIES) ArrayList<CommunityModel>communityList
    );
```

My retrofit helper to get ArrayList is as below

```
public ArrayList<CommunityModel> getcommunities() {
        final ArrayList<CommunityModel> returnCommunityList = new ArrayList<>();
        //final int userId = mIntent.getIntExtra(UserAccount.KEY_USER_ID, 0);
        final String serverToken ="Basic"+" "+localSession.getServerToken();
        DebugLog.i(NetworkOperationService.class.getSimpleName(), "servertoken"+serverToken);
        Call<ArrayList<CommunityModel>> communityCall = mNetworkOperation.getCommunities(serverToken, localSession.getUserId(),);
        communityCall.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<CommunityModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<CommunityModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<CommunityModel>> response) {

                DebugLog.i(NetworkOperationService.class.getSimpleName(), "servertoken"+serverToken+"userid="+localSession.getUserId());

                if (response!=null && response.code()==200)
                {
                    DebugLog.i(NetworkOperationService.class.getSimpleName(), "200");
                    ArrayList<CommunityModel> arrayList = response.body();

                    for (int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
                    {
                        returnCommunityList.add(arrayList.get(i));
                        DebugLog.i(NetworkOperationService.class.getSimpleName(), arrayList.get(i).getCommunityName());
                    }
                }
                else{
                    DebugLog.i(NetworkOperationService.class.getSimpleName(), "respose code"+response.code());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<CommunityModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });

        return returnCommunityList;
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated ... i am not able to get the response ...
i wan the response in the same manner as given above...

please help

Comment: any error? please add log

Comment: i am getting error 400...because it is accepting headers for authentication ....so now i have added header its giving response... i would like to know difference between query() parameter and headers()

Answer (score 0):

> You can try the following code to send header field with retrofit.

```
public interface UserService {  
    @GET("/tasks")
    Call<List<Task>> getTasks(@Header("Content-Range") String contentRange);
}
```

> Otherwise You can try by using OkHttpClient:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();  
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {  
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        Request request = original.newBuilder()
            .header("User-Agent", "Your-App-Name")
            .header("Accept", "application/vnd.yourapi.v1.full+json")
            .method(original.method(), original.body())
            .build();

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}

OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();  
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build();
```